# No module named impacket

Tags: python, pip, impacket

I have installed impacket and its requirements on windows, but when I want to execute a python file (in my case `send_and_execute.py 192.168.x.x sample.exe`), the message:

```
File ..., line 2, in <module>
 From impacket import smb, smbconnection importerror: no module named impacket
```

will appeared. I have tested it on two windows systems, but the problem has not been solved. What is the problem?
It is necessary to mention that Initially I installed PyCrypto, then I executed these commands and the installation process was apparently successful:

```
py -m pip install pyasn1
py -m pip install pyasn1-modules
py -m pip install impacket
```

Comment: Exactly how are you executing the command?  It's not uncommon today for a system to have multiple Python installations.

Comment: I have python 2.7 and 3.4, but the commands that i have mentioned are exactly what I have run in cmd.

Comment: Python ***3.5*** is EOL (not maintained at all any more), so **3.4** is even more so. I'd recommend upgrading.

Comment: If you type `py -V`, which does it tell you?  I can't help but think that your `pip` call is installing in one, and your `send_and_execute.py` is invoking the other.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Python 3.8.5

Comment: Then clearly your assertion that "I have python 2.7 and 3.4" is wrong.  Where do you think the 3.8.5 version is coming from?

Comment: @Tim Roberts With this situation do I have to delete all versions except 3.8.5?

Comment: Not at all, you just need to make sure the "pip" you are running is for the version of Python you're hoping to use.  This is why people often run pip like `python -m pip install ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install it from there? https://github.com/SecureAuthCorp/impacket

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not get an answer from this method either.